# Exporting dataset react native to different format

Tags: javascript, react-native, export

Export dataset from react to all different formats .doc .txt and other?
Is there a set of tools or packages to export datasets from react native to different formats?

Because I only found packages that can export to Excel format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for npm packages that support the format you're looking for. React is not a format. Example: you can use the npm package `docx` to generate a word document in the browser, or in your case a react native app.

Keep in mind that using a cloud service for this is also a great choice since .Net has excellent support for MS Office file formats. You could create your own service or use something like: https://cloudconvert.com/